# Doesn't detect dates

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am doing some operations with the functions `isoweek` and `if_else` but some dates do not perform the operation obtaining `NA`.

[image]

```
db = read_dta("C:/Users/crist/Downloads/db.dta")


db$date1 = substr(db$date1,1,10)
db$date1 = as.Date(db$date1)
db$date2 = substr(db$date2,1,10)
db$date2 = as.Date(db$date2)

t = db %>% 
  drop_na(value) %>% 
  mutate(Weekday = weekdays(date2),
         date2 = replace(date2, Weekday %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), NA),
         num_week = isoweek(date2),
         dummy_sas = if_else(date2 >= ymd("2020-05-18"),1,0)) %>% 
  fill(date2)  %>% 
  select(-Weekday) %>% 
  mutate(date2 = if_else(date2 < as.Date("2020-05-18") & SAS == 1, date1, date2))
```

> I need for example all the week numbers but i get NA's

```
> summary(isoweek(t$date2))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00   22.00   31.00   28.15   39.00   47.00 
> summary(t$num_week)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   1.00   21.00   31.00   28.12   39.00   47.00     109
```

Data [here](https://mega.nz/file/FgQiBBDb#BfhdaQW8c8hhbXEba_2U5nE9kOj9uW9aGaDFIw5-pbQ)

Comment: Can you share a small sample subset of your data with `dput` and show your expected output for it? Also `if_else(date2 >= 2020-05-18,1,0)` looks wrong. `2020-05-18` returns 1997.

Comment: I just updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't downloaded the data but I think order of operation seems to be an issue here. Try this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

db %>% 
  drop_na(value) %>% 
  mutate(Weekday = weekdays(date2),
         num_week = isoweek(date2),
         date2 = replace(date2, Weekday %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), NA),
         dummy_sas = as.integer(date2 >= ymd("2020-05-18"))) %>%
  fill(date2)  %>% 
  select(-Weekday) %>% 
  mutate(date2 = if_else(date2 < as.Date("2020-05-18") & SAS == 1, date1, date2))
```

---

In your code you replace weekends with `NA` :

```
date2 = replace(date2, Weekday %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), NA)
```

and then take `isoweek` on `date2`.

```
num_week = isoweek(date2)
```

So weekends would give `NA` in `num_week`.

You replace `date2` again in last line

```
mutate(date2 = if_else(date2 < as.Date("2020-05-18") & SAS == 1, date1, date2))
```

so you don't get any `NA`s in `t$date2`.